# How to specify different git account when visiting different ip or host?

Tags: git, github, ssh, git-config

I have to use different git account for the intranet and extranet for developing and software maintenance task.
For example, I have to set some proxies so I can `ssh` connect to the extranet but the extranet git account is different with the intranet one. So if set it global like `git config --global user.name "user"` it will cause some troubles when trying to `ssh` connect to git repository in the different web environment.
So I want to know how to set the different `git` account configuration for the different environment.
Here are my `.gitconfig` right now.

```
[http "http://git.intranet.com"]
    proxy = http://127.0.0.3:0303
[http "https://git.intranet.com"]
    proxy = http://127.0.0.3:0303
[user]
    name = bowen
    email = bowen@email.com
```

Could anyone help me and give some examples or hints? 
Thanks in advances.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to use different git accounts when you trying to connect to intranet and extranet?

Comment: @NithishGandesiri yes, I try to use different git accounts when connecting to the intranet and extranet git repository website. And I find a way that I can modify git config in the different local git repository.

Comment: "*`git config --global user.name "user"` it will cause some troubles when trying to `ssh`*" It doesn't. `user.name`/`user.email` configuration values are used **only** to create commits, not for authorization. SSH authorization is performed using ssh keypairs or host passwords. HTTP authorization is performed using passwords.

Comment: So in that scenario what I could think of is providing different ssh keys for those accounts in `~/.ssh/config` so that the corresponding keys will be used for the authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Creating SSH Config file

If you not having `config` file already then go ahead and create it.

```
cd ~/.ssh/
touch config
code config  //command code will be used to open this file in visual code
```

If config file is already available then add SSH configuration rules for different hosts so that the config will be helpful to pick the corresponding identity file to use for the provided domain.

```
# Intranet account--> default
Host github.com
   HostName github.com
   User <user>
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

# Extranet account
Host github.com-extranet    
   HostName github.com
   User <user>
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_extranet
```

Whatever is provided as `Host` is most important as this will be used for cloning or setting up the remote origin.

`ssh-agent` will use

- `id_rsa` the key for any Git URL that uses @github.com
- `id_rsa_extranet` the key for any Git URL that uses @github.com-extranet

In order to use intranet credentials for accessing the repo, execute the below commands

```
ssh-add -D              //removes all ssh entries from the ssh-agent
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa   // Adds the relevant ssh key
```

To push or access using extranet credentials

```
ssh-add -D
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_extranet
```

## For setting up/updating Extranet Repositories in local

- To update the remote origin URL

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com-extranet:<user>/repo_name.git
```

- To init and add it as the Git remote to the local repository.

```
git init
git remote add origin git@github.com-extranet:<user>/repo_name.git
```

Hope this helps. For more info about ssh keys and all the process please go through this [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/manage-multiple-github-accounts-the-ssh-way-2dadc30ccaca/)